# How do I split up the following Python string in to a list of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I have a string `'Predicate(big,small)'`

How do I derive the following list of strings from that, `['Predicate','(','big',',','small',')']`

The names can potentially be anything, and there can also be spaces between elements like so (I need to have the whitespace taken out of the list), `Predicate (big, small)`

So far I've tried this, but this is clearly not the result that I want

```
>>> str1 = 'Predicate(big,small)'
>>> list(map(str,str1))
```

Output:

```
['P', 'r', 'e', 'd', 'i', 'c', 'a', 't', 'e', '(', 'b', 'i', 'g', ',', 's', 'm', 'a', 'l', 'l', ')']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.split()` to split your string on `(` or `)`. You can capture the delimiters in the regex to include them in your final output. Combined with `str.strip()` to handle spaces and filtering out any ending empty strings you get something like:

```
import re

s = 'Predicate ( big ,small )'
[s.strip() for s in  re.split(r'([\(\),])', s.strip()) if s]
# ['Predicate', '(', 'big', ',', 'small', ')']
```

Comment: This looks much better. +1 Edited my answer to not catch spaces ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, I don't think I made it very clear but I was also looking to have the ',' as an element within the list, dividing up the list element 'big, small' in to three elements instead :  

  'big', ',' ,'small'

Comment: @Biggeez yes, I didn't catch that. You can just add the `,` to the regex. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `re` here.

```
import re
text='Predicate(big,small)'
parsed=re.findall(r'\w+|[^a-zA-Z,\s])
# ['Predicate', '(', 'big', 'small', ')']
```

1. `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).
2. `[^a-zA-Z,\s]` matches a single character not present in the list.
3. `\s` for matching space.

Comment: can you pls explain what the 3rd line is doing

Comment: This seems to have some issues with the requirement in the OP: `(I need to have the whitespace taken out of the list)` given a string like `'Predicate( big, small)'`

Comment: @MarkMeyer My bad I missed it. Adding `\s`  to not match spaces will suffice I guess.

Comment: @Biggeez Added explanation. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, was wondering how you would have to change the code if I wanted to facilitate having numbers and underscores as well as part of the names

Comment: @Biggeez `\w+` will match numbers and underscore too

Comment: Glad to help @Biggeez